# Question about Convolution terminology (analog to mean, variance, skewness, kurtosis,...)

Tags: probability, convolution

In probability theory we have mean, variance, skewness, kurtosis and etc. Can we use the same terms for a convolution (kernel) that sums to 1?

For example, can we say a $1$-D convolution kernel $[3/2,-2,3/2]$ has mean $0$ and $\sigma= 3$?

I'm wondering what basic results generalize from probability distributions to convolutions, or if there are any references that people would recommend (background: math and phy undergrad and grad.). Thanks!

Comment: exactly what do you mean by the word "convolution"???

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich It sounds like they mean a convolution with a kernel, like Gaussian blur or edge detection in image processing, and they're asking about features of the kernel.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thanks for the response! I should clarify that I am referring to a convolution kernel, not the  entire operation.

Comment: @ElliotYu yes that is what I'm asking. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you work with non-negative kernels, then after the normalization, you can treat it as a distribution of a delta-signal after one convolution step. So it's natural to talk about statistics of such distribution. **Important:**  it's not the values statistics, it's position statistics assuming the values are probabilities. So if you have a kernel $[0.25, 0.5, 0.25]$ and assume the positions are $[-1,0,1]$, then the mean and sigma are
$$m=-1\times0.25 +0\times 0.5+1\times0.25 = 0\\
\sigma=(-1)^2\times0.25+0^2\times0.5+1^2\times0.25=0.5$$

However, if you want to treat the numbers in the kernel as a set and calculate statistics over those, it makes little sense.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I definitely agree with the probability being position statistics when the kernel is non-negative. However, for a kernel that has negative entries, it seems to me that its properties are still entirely determined by its $<r^n>$ values , which of course are not "moments", but I am not sure what to call them. (assuming the positions are $[...,-2,-1,0,1,2,...]$)

Comment: You can still calculate $\sum u_rr^n$, but since those values are not normalized, it's hard to compare them between different kernels. So I am not sure about its usefulness. I believe, you can call them [function moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(mathematics)) just fine

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!